# Closure operator and set of fixpoint

Tags: closure-properties, lattices

In chapter 2.2 of

*Giacobazzi, Roberto; Ranzato, Francesco*, [**Uniform closures: Order-theoretically reconstructing logic program semantics and abstract domain refinements**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/inco.1998.2724), Inf. Comput. 145, No.2, 153-190 (1998). [ZBL0921.68057](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0921.68057).

it's said:

> An  (upper) closure  operator (or simply closure) on a poset $C$ is  an  operator $\rho:C \to C$ monotone, idempotent and extensive (i.e.,
>   $\forall x \in C . x \le \rho(x)$). We denote by $uco(C)$ the set of all closure operators on the poset $C$. **If $C$ is a complete lattice then each closure operator $uco(C)$ is uniquely  determined  by the set  of its  fixpoints, which is its image $\rho(C)$**

Where can I find a proof of the phrase in bold?

Comment: Check the sample pages of this monograph: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387308043. The result you want is Theorem 2.1.2.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thank you very much, I'm checking it right now. Later I'll add a response

Comment: @YuvalFilmus if you want to add the theorem as answer, I'll accept that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an intimate connection between closure operators and complete lattices.

Given a closure operator $C$ on a set $X$, we can construct a complete lattice $L(C)$ as follows:

- The points of the lattice are the fixpoints of $C$.
- The meet of the lattice is $A \wedge B = A \cap B$.
- The join of the lattice is $A \vee B = C(A \cup B)$.

Conversely, given a complete lattice $L$ of subsets of $X$, we can construct a closure operator $C:=C(L)$ on $X$ using the formula
$$ C(A) = \bigcap \{ B \in L : B \supseteq A \}. $$

It turns out that these two operators are inverses:
$C(L(C)) = C$ and $L(C(L)) = L$.

In particular, this shows that $C$ is determined by the set $L(C)$ of fixpoints, since
$$
C(A) = \bigcap \{B \in L(C) : B \supseteq A\}.
$$

(This information is taken from the sample chapter of [M-solid varieties of algebras](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387308043) by Koppitz and Denecke.)